# GDPR - Offshoring

Tags: gdpr, data-protection

We work for consulting company in India, call it Z.
Z has a partnership with a European cards & transactions processing company Y.

So the Indian consulting company Z does offshore production support for European Company Y. And as part of live production support Indian consultants have read access to sensitive data.

Per new GDPR rules: Can consultants in India view European data outside the EU?

Answer (score 1):

GDPR also applies to foreign companies. Look at article 3.2 of the GDPR:

> Article 3: Territorial scope
>
> 1. This Regulation applies to the processing of personal data in the context of the activities of an establishment of a controller or a
>      processor in the Union, regardless of whether the processing takes
>      place in the Union or not.
> 2. This Regulation applies to the processing of personal data of data subjects who are in the Union by a controller or processor not
>      established in the Union, where the processing activities are related
>      to: (a) the offering of goods or services, irrespective of whether a
>      payment of the data subject is required, to such data subjects in the
>      Union; or (b) the monitoring of their behaviour as far as their
>      behaviour takes place within the Union.
> 3. This Regulation applies to the processing of personal data by a controller not established in the Union, but in a place where Member
>      State law applies by virtue of public international law.